# javascript array method sort returns 120 larger than 50

Tags: javascript

the following code sorts the integers in the array wrong in which it the result is: 1,10,100,30,40,50,80

```
var arr = new Array();

arr = [50,100,30,40,80,10,1];

var z = arr.sort();

console.error(z);
```

Comment: I know it's counter-intuitive but it sorts data from A to Z as [documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: `var arr = [50,100,30,40,80,10,1];
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
console.log(arr);
` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: PROTIP: Don't use `new Array()`, you can just do `var arr = [50,100,30,40,80,10,1];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because it's sorting them as *strings* not numbers.  From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> If `compareFunction` is not supplied, elements are sorted by converting them to **strings** and comparing strings in Unicode code point order. For example, "Banana" comes before "cherry". In a *numeric* sort, 9 comes before 80, but because numbers are converted to strings, "80" comes before "9" in Unicode order.

What you need to do is give it a callback to sort them as numbers:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b){
    return a - b;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs for [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), the "default sort order is according to string Unicode code points." This will give you a lexical sort, which you typically don't want for numbers.

Specifically, [section 22.1.3.24.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-sortcompare) of the [ECMAscript spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0) defines the normal sort function, with steps 5 and 7 explicitly converting the arguments to strings:

> 5. Let `xString` be ToString(`x`).
> 6. ReturnIfAbrupt(`xString`).
> 7. Let `yString` be ToString(`y`).
> 8. ReturnIfAbrupt(`yString`).
> 9. If `xString < yString`, return −1.
> 10. If `xString > yString`, return 1.
> 11. Return +0.

You should provide your own sort function that does not treat values as strings, like:

```js
var arr = new Array();

arr = [50, 100, 30, 40, 80, 10, 1];

var z = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a < b) return -1;
  if (b < a) return +1;
  return 0;
});

console.log(z);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sort()` method sorts the items of an array.

The sort order can be either alphabetic or numeric, and either ascending (up) or descending (down).

By default, the sort() method sorts the values as strings in alphabetical and ascending order.

This works well for strings `("Apple" comes before "Banana")`. However, if numbers are sorted as strings, "25" is bigger than "100", because "2" is bigger than "1".

Because of this, the sort() method will produce an incorrect result when sorting numbers.

You can fix this by providing a "compare function" : `array.sort(compareFunction)`

```
var points = [50, 100, 30, 40, 80, 10, 1];
points.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
console.log(points); 
o/p: 1,10,30,40,50,80,100
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1atq1yyd/)